# PHP create array from a string

Tags: php, arrays

i have a string it looks like this:

```
brand[split]bmw[split]year[split]2008[split]model[split]730D
```

I want it to convert to an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [brand] => bmw [year] => 2008 [model] => 730D )
```

is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[explode()](http://php.net/explode) will split a string into an array of pieces:

```
$string = "brand[split]bmw[split]year[split]2008[split]model[split]730D";
$array = explode("[split]", $string);
```

Then you want to join the first to the second, third to the fourth etc:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $result[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
    $i++;
}
```

This returns:

```
array:3 [▼
  "brand" => "bmw"
  "year" => "2008"
  "model" => "730D"
]
```

Comment: it creates multiple arrays: ``Array ( [0] => Array ( [brand] => bmw ) [1] => Array ( [year] => 2008 ) [2] => Array ( [model] => 730D ) [3] => Array ( [] => ) [4] => Array ( [] => ) [5] => Array ( [] => ) )``

Comment: Just updated the answer with an improved answer (using for instead of foreach).

Comment: You're welcome. I don't like the `$i++` inside the `for` loop, but I'm not sure how to `$i+2` in the third expression :s